# Docker Engine not running in Mac M1 series

Tags: macos, docker, docker-desktop

Problem : I was trying to set up Docker on my Mac M1, docker engine was somehow keep running (it was in kind of hung state). When I tried running docker ps command, I used to get the error "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: In Docker Desktop go to settings and try these two steps:-

1. Clean/purge data
2. Reset to Factory defaults.

Doing this helped me to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh — Both of these options fixed the issue for me.